# when i press a button, two buttons are being pressed, pygame

Tags: python, pygame

When I press a button, two buttons are being pressed.
I made images to act like a button but when I press the first button, the second button is pressed too.
I'm new to pygame and trying to make the buttons do separate things when I click each one.

```py
import pygame
import time

pygame.init();
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((340,340));
img = pygame.image.load('3.gif')
iimg = pygame.image.load('2.gif')
mg = pygame.image.load('4.gif').convert()
g = pygame.image.load('5.gif')
waitingForInput = False
pygame.display.set_caption("SIMON");
BEEP1 = pygame.mixer.Sound('beep1.wav')
BEEP2 = pygame.mixer.Sound('beep2.wav')
BEEP3 = pygame.mixer.Sound('beep3.wav')
BEEP4 = pygame.mixer.Sound('beep4.wav')
screen.blit(img,(0,0))
screen.blit(mg,(150,0))
pygame.display.flip()

def main():
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return False

            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                mouse_pos = event.pos

                if img.get_rect().collidepoint(mouse_pos):
                    print ('button was pressed at {0}'.format(mouse_pos))
                    BEEP1.play()
                    screen.blit(iimg,(0,0))
                    pygame.display.flip()
                    time.sleep(.30)
                    screen.blit(img,(0,0))
                    pygame.display.flip()


                if mg.get_rect().collidepoint(mouse_pos):
                    print ('button was pressed at {0}'.format(mouse_pos))
                    BEEP2.play()
                    screen.blit(g,(150,0))
                    pygame.display.flip()
                    time.sleep(.30)
                    screen.blit(mg,(150,0))
                    pygame.display.flip()

main()
```

Comment: ..on another note: You might want to change `software prgrammer at apple` to `software programmer at apple` in your profile ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you call `get_rect` on a `Surface`, the resulting `Rect` that is returned will always have an `x` and `y` value of `0`.

So when you run `if img.get_rect().collidepoint(mouse_pos)` in your event loop, you're NOT checking if the `Surface` was a clicked. You check if the mouse position is in the top left corner of the screen.

Maybe use some `print` statements to check for yourself.

What you can do is to create a `Rect` for each button *outside* of your main loop, and then use these rects for blitting:

```
...
img = pygame.image.load('3.gif')
img_rect = img.get_rect()
...
mg = pygame.image.load('4.gif').convert()
mg_rect = img.get_rect(topleft=(150,0))
...
while True:
   ...
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            mouse_pos = event.pos

            if img_rect().collidepoint(mouse_pos):
                BEEP1.play()

            if mg_rect ().collidepoint(mouse_pos):
                BEEP2.play()

    screen.blit(img, img_rect)
    screen.blit(mg, mg_rect)
```

Note that you also should avoid `time.sleep` or multiple calls of `pygame.display.flip()` in your main loop.

Another solution is to use the pygame's `Sprite` class, which allows you to combine a `Surface` and a `Rect`.